# Cannot find elements by class jQuery in just inserted HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

```
render:function () {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({url:'/db/list.json', dataType:'JSON'}).done(function (json) {
        var html = tmpl['video-list']({videos:json});
        self.$el.html(html);
    });

    console.log($('.video-thumb-box'));

    $.each($('.video-thumb-box'), function(){
        console.log(this);
        $(this).bind('mouseenter', function(){
            console.log($('.video-thumb-info', this));
        });
    });
}
```

`tmpl['video-list']({videos:json})` is underscore template and contain list of items in `DIV`s here is example return

```
<div class="span3">
    <a href="#/video/123">
        <div class="video-thumb-box">
            <img class="video-thumb-img" src="test" alt="Video tumbnail">
            <div class="video-thumb-info hide">
                <img class="pull-right" width="16" height="16" src="/img/icons/namba.png">
                something
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="span3">
    <a href="#/video/123">
        <div class="video-thumb-box">
            <img class="video-thumb-img" src="test" alt="Video tumbnail">
            <div class="video-thumb-info hide">
                <img class="pull-right" width="16" height="16" src="/img/icons/namba.png">
                something
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Why cannot I find anything in `$('.video-thumb-box')`?

Comment: You would need to call `.render` again

Comment: `$.ajax` is async. You need to do the loop after the Ajax call completes. (For example, move the code into the function block in `done`.

Comment: That is exactly the reason of the problem. I have just moved `$.each` into `done()` and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

your each loop is backwards.

```
$('.video-thumb-box').each(function() {
    console.log(this);
    $(this).bind('mouseenter', function(){
        console.log($('.video-thumb-info', this));
    });
});
```

Here's the jQuery `.each()` [API](http://api.jquery.com/each/) page